# vpython "relative" rotating a frame

Tags: rotation, vpython

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate a frame-object relative to its current position.

e.g. An object is pointing north, and i say rotate around the y-axis 180 degrees. And after that I say: tilt 90 degrees it tilts it from the "world" perspective. So it is pointing down instead op up. (Sorry for this confusing story, if you try the code below and use your up-down-left-right keys you see what i mean).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    import time
    import numpy
    from visual import *

    # initialize variables
    pitch_degrees = 0
    roll_degrees = 0
    yaw_degrees = 0

    xangle = 0.0
    yangle = 0.0
    zangle = 0.0

    # create the airplane frame. this will be our working object.
    airplane = frame(make_trail=True)
    # below are the elements that create the airplane
    body = cone(frame=airplane, pos=(50,0,0), axis=(-150,0,0), radius=10)
    body2 = cone(frame=airplane, pos=(50,0,0), axis=(50,0,0), radius=10)
    wing = box(frame=airplane, pos=(35,0,0), size=(30,3,180))
    tail = box(frame=airplane, pos=(-75,0,0), size=(20,3,50))
    aileron = box(frame=airplane, pos=(-75,12,0), size=(20,24,3))
    cabin = ellipsoid(frame=airplane, pos=(30,5,0), axis=(1,0,0),size=(45,24,12))
    #painting
    for obj in airplane.objects:
        obj.color = color.red

    body.color = color.white
    cabin.color = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    cabin.opacity = 0.8

    # I'm experiencing some jitter in my screen when starting up (yay ati....)
    time.sleep(2)

    # loop forever
    while True:
            # are there any keys pressed? if so, act on them.
            if scene.kb.keys: # event waiting to be processed?
                    s = scene.kb.getkey() # get keyboard info
                    if (s == 'up'):
                            pitch_degrees = pitch_degrees - 1
                    if (s == 'down'):
                            pitch_degrees = pitch_degrees + 1
                    if (s == 'left'):
                            roll_degrees = roll_degrees - 1
                    if (s == 'right'):
                            roll_degrees = roll_degrees + 1

            # convert degrees to radians
            zangle = numpy.radians(pitch_degrees)
            xangle = numpy.radians(roll_degrees)

            # execute the actual rotation.
            # but this should be relative to its current rotation :(
            airplane.rotate(angle=zangle,axis=(0,0,1))
            airplane.rotate(angle=xangle,axis=(1,0,0))

            # some delay because i'm a dirty boy
            time.sleep(0.005)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class that is an airplane rather than a frame. This way you can have a method for the airplane class that rotates every item in the class (wing, tail, etc) relative to the position and orientation of the airplane. So the class would contain a vector that is its position as well as a vector for its orientation. Then use rotation math to rotate each item individually about the airplane's orientation vector.

Sorry, I would post this in comments but I don't have enough reputation :)